# PhpStorm, is there a way to add a breakpoint to all methods for a class?

Tags: phpstorm

I would like to add breakpoints to all methods in a php class. I found the below window (Run -> View Breakpoints -> +), but it's not clear to me if there's a way to wildcard this such that it will stop on all methods in a class.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, wildcards aren't supported there.